# What is the main difference between Quantum Clusters and Nanoclusters?

Tags: nomenclature, nanotechnology

I know that Quantum Dots have high quantum yield and ranges from 2nm-10nm, and Nanoclusters have high fluorescence and ranges from 1nm-10nm. But the difference between them is that Quantum Dots exhibits red shift as the size gets larger while vice versa for Nanoclusters. My guess is Quantum Clusters is the combination of both, size is less than 2nm and exhibits red shift as size gets larger. Is this correct? Are there more things that distinguish them to each other?

Comment: Since these are frequently used as terms to describe a variety of different materials, it might help if you can specify some examples of this usage.. My immediate response is "nano clusters of *what* exactly.."

Comment: @Geoff Hutchison What I mean by Nanoclusters is Gold Nanoclusters.

Comment: OK, but what do you mean by "quantum clusters"? I don't think I've ever heard that term.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison There are papers already published about gold quantum clusters, but my concern is that the mechanism of gold nanoclusters are, as the size gets larger it tend to have a blueshift, while quantum dots tend to have a redshift as size gets larger. There some papers that were published and titled their paper gold nanoclusters but the properties exhibited is like QDs, redshift as size gets larger. So I'm confused, why not call it quantum clusters since its size is less than 2nm and it exhibited redshift?

Comment: Calling sth "Nanoclusters" or "quantum clusters" doesn't even sound scientific - more like sth found in commmercial.

Comment: @iso345 Scientific communication is precise. This means you must pick terms that others will find understandable. Quantum dots and metal clusters are *very* different materials, and attempting to hybridize terms is likely to be very confusing.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer: "quantum clusters" is not widespread and likely confusing. I'd suggest "small nanoparticles" or perhaps "metal nano clusters."**

I can't comment on optical shifts, but many of these properties are distinct to the particular material and the onset of quantized energy levels in that material. So I doubt you can simply combine properties of quantum dots and nanoparticles.

I asked a colleague who synthesizes gold nanoparticles. She hasn’t heard anyone use the term "quantum clusters" and thinks people would find it very confusing.

Typically the usage:

- **Quantum Dots** refer to semiconductor nanoparticles, e.g., $\ce{CdS}$ or $\ce{PbSe}$ etc.
- **Nanoparticles** refer to nanometer-sized particles of basically anything (proteins, polymers, metals, etc.)
- **Clusters** refer to *very* small particles (i.e., <1-2 nm diameter) with well-defined numbers of atoms (i.e., a few hundred at most). There is an [IUPAC *Gold Book*](http://goldbook.iupac.org/CT06769.html) definition:

  > A number of metal centres grouped close together which can have direct metal bonding interactions or interactions through a bridging ligand, but are not necessarily held together by these interactions.

For reference, Wikipedia suggests [nanoclusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanoclusters) are aggregates of nanoparticles. I don't think that's in common use, but certainly it suggests *your* suggested term would be very confusing.